# if not line: raise EOFError when using urllib.urlretrieve

Tags: python, ftp, urllib

I have to download multiple files from a FTP link. but the download stops with the above error exactly after 5 files irrespective of the order. Can anyone suggest a solution

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import urllib
import zipfile

zipFilePath=['ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/data/1000069/000089418911000620/0000894189-11-000620-xbrl.zip',
 'ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/data/1000180/000100018011000006/0001000180-11-000006-xbrl.zip',
 'ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/data/1000228/000100022811000014/0001000228-11-000014-xbrl.zip',
 'ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/data/1000229/000100022911000015/0001000229-11-000015-xbrl.zip',
 'ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/data/1000351/000089418911000615/0000894189-11-000615-xbrl.zip',
 'ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/data/1000351/000089418911000655/0000894189-11-000655-xbrl.zip',
 'ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/data/1000697/000095012311018381/0000950123-11-018381-xbrl.zip',
 'ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/data/1000753/000114036111008714/0001140361-11-008714-xbrl.zip',
 'ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/data/1001039/000119312511027450/0001193125-11-027450-xbrl.zip',
 'ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/data/1001082/000110465911009436/0001104659-11-009436-xbrl.zip',
 'ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/data/100122/000095012311020431/0000950123-11-020431-xbrl.zip',
 'ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/data/1001250/000110465911005139/0001104659-11-005139-xbrl.zip',
 'ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/data/1001288/000095012311019815/0000950123-11-019815-xbrl.zip',
 'ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/data/1001604/000100160411000022/0001001604-11-000022-xbrl.zip',
 'ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/data/1001838/000110465911011083/0001104659-11-011083-xbrl.zip',
 'ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/data/1002047/000119312511056223/0001193125-11-056223-xbrl.zip',
 'ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/data/1002517/000095012311011086/0000950123-11-011086-xbrl.zip',
 'ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/data/1002638/000119312511022882/0001193125-11-022882-xbrl.zip',
 'ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/data/1002718/000119312511040571/0001193125-11-040571-xbrl.zip',
 'ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/data/1002718/000119312511042365/0001193125-11-042365-xbrl.zip']

tempFolderPath = "<give some path>"
tempDownloadPath=os.path.join(tempFolderPath,"xbrl.zip")
xbrlFinal=pd.DataFrame()
for inds,paths in enumerate(zipFilePath):
    print "processing xmls " + str(inds+1) +" of " + str(len(zipFilePath))
    urllib.urlretrieve(paths,tempDownloadPath)
    fh=open(tempDownloadPath,'rb')
    z=zipfile.ZipFile(fh)
    files=z.extract(z.namelist()[0], tempFolderPath)
    z.close()
    fh.close()
```

Comment: No, since we do not see your code.

Comment: Where are the *above errors*? show some code.

Comment: i have added the code.

Comment: maybe the site doesn't allow requests that quickly.  Can you pause between requests?

Answer (score 0):

i figured the answer. Actually the download works fine in R so the site is not imposing any request problems. I tried different packages in python, urllib, wget and requests did not work but urllib2 worked. the code is given below:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(paths)
zipcontent= response.read()
with open(tempDownloadPath, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(zipcontent)
```

and urllib2 is 5 times faster than the rest